# How to troubleshoot broken link for mailing list subscription confirmation

Tags: groups, mailing

we have routinely used the option for users to register for a mailing list via a mailing group. Also we automatically send out an Email for confirming the registration (double-opt-in). Unfortunately the link in the email is broken, it directs to
WEBSITE/civicrm/mailing/confirm/?reset=1&cid=XXX&sid=YYY&h=HASH, which gives a "site not found" error.

I flushed the Cache and reset the paths, but the error remains.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

What solved the problem for me (civiCRM 5.59.2., WP 6.4.3):
The WP instance needs to update the permalinks regularly, under: WEBSITE/wp-admin/options-permalink.php

On the way, I found out that you can edit the message for the automatic email for subscription under Administer > CiviMail > Header, Footer and Automatic messages; in my case it uses the token {subscribe.url} which is hard coded, and correct. The update of the WP permalinks did the trick.